# Swap Exact Tokens for Tokens Errors

Tags: token, solidity, swap

I’ve been trying to get a Swap ExactTokenforToken swap via uniswap for a while now. Keep coming up on issues.

I did have a contract that successfully deployed, but it kept getting a transfer error. My understanding from looking at documentation, posts, this forum, etc is that I didn't have the transfer/approve events.

Here is that code, which deployed but cannot swap, for reference:

```
pragma solidity 0.7.1;

import "https://github.com/Uniswap/uniswap-v2-periphery/blob/master/contracts/interfaces/IUniswapV2Router02.sol";

contract UniswapExample {
  address internal constant UNISWAP_ROUTER_ADDRESS = 0x7a250d5630B4cF539739dF2C5dAcb4c659F2488D ;

  IUniswapV2Router02 public uniswapRouter;
  address private multiDaiKovan = 0x4F96Fe3b7A6Cf9725f59d353F723c1bDb64CA6Aa;
  address private USDC = 0x2F375e94FC336Cdec2Dc0cCB5277FE59CBf1cAe5;
  
  constructor() {
    uniswapRouter = IUniswapV2Router02(UNISWAP_ROUTER_ADDRESS);
  }
  
  function convertUSDCtoEthtoDai(uint daiAmount, uint USDCAmount) public payable {
    uint deadline = block.timestamp + 15; // using 'now' for convenience, for mainnet pass deadline from frontend!
    uniswapRouter.swapExactTokensForTokens(USDCAmount, daiAmount, getPathForETHtoDAI(), address(this), deadline);
    // refund leftover ETH to user
    (bool success,) = msg.sender.call{ value: address(this).balance }("");
    require(success, "refund failed");

  }
  
  
  function getEstimatedETHforDAI(uint daiAmount) public view returns (uint[] memory) {
    return uniswapRouter.getAmountsIn(daiAmount, getPathForETHtoDAI());
  }

  function getPathForETHtoDAI() private view returns (address[] memory) {
    address[] memory path = new address[](3);
    path[0] = USDC;
    path[1] = uniswapRouter.WETH();
    path[2] = multiDaiKovan;
    
    return path;
  }
 
  
  // important to receive ETH
  receive() payable external {}
}
```

So I worked my way to the following code, however, I’m getting an error on “.transferFrom” saying “TypeError: Member “transferFrom” not found or not visible after argument-dependent lookup in address.”

Same is happening on .approve. I’ve imported the IERC20 interfaces for Router02 & IERC20. So I an unable to deploy the contract to test if I'm getting close.

Here is the new code:

```
import "https://github.com/Uniswap/uniswap-v2-periphery/blob/master/contracts/interfaces/IUniswapV2Router02.sol";
import "https://github.com/Uniswap/uniswap-v2-periphery/blob/master/contracts/interfaces/IERC20.sol";

contract UniswapExample2 {

    address internal constant UNISWAP_ROUTER_ADDRESS = 0x7a250d5630B4cF539739dF2C5dAcb4c659F2488D ;

    IUniswapV2Router02 public uniswapRouter;
    address private multiDaiKovan = 0x4F96Fe3b7A6Cf9725f59d353F723c1bDb64CA6Aa;
    address private USDC = 0x2F375e94FC336Cdec2Dc0cCB5277FE59CBf1cAe5;
  
    constructor() {
     uniswapRouter = IUniswapV2Router02(UNISWAP_ROUTER_ADDRESS);
  }
    function swapTokenForETH(uint amountIn, uint amountOutMin, uint deadline) public payable returns(uint[] memory) {
        // transfer
        require(USDC.transferFrom(msg.sender, address(this), amountIn), 'transferFrom failed.');
        // approve
        require(USDC.approve(UNISWAP_ROUTER_ADDRESS, amountIn), 'approve failed.');
        // swap
        return uniswapRouter.swapExactTokensForTokens(amountIn, amountOutMin, getPathForETHtoDAI(), msg.sender, deadline);
    }
    
    
    function getPathForETHtoDAI() private view returns (address[] memory) {
    address[] memory path = new address[](3);
    path[0] = USDC;
    path[1] = uniswapRouter.WETH();
    path[2] = multiDaiKovan;
    
    return path;
  }
}
```

I’ve also tried to replicate the functions inside the actual contract, but then I get an error saying the entire contract must be marked as abstract.

Any suggestions/guidance would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to execute the `transferFrom()` function on an `address` type (where it's undefined).

```
<address>.transferFrom()
```

It needs to be on an interface that defines the `transferFrom()` function.

```
interface IERC20 {
    function transferFrom(address _from, address _to, uint256 _amount) external returns (bool);
}

contract UniswapExample2 {
    IERC20 private USDC = IERC20(0x2F375e94FC336Cdec2Dc0cCB5277FE59CBf1cAe5);

    function swapTokenForETH() public {
        USDC.transferFrom();
    }
}
```

*Note: You're already (correctly) doing the same thing with the `IUniswapV2Router02` interface, `uniswapRouter` property, and the method `swapExactTokensForTokens()`.*

Comment: Thank you for your answer. That makes a lot of sense!